# Resolving Postfix virtual maps

Tags: postfix, mac-osx-server

I am getting this error while trying to install virtualmin virtual servers on Mac OS X

```
A problem was found with your Postfix virtual maps : No map sources were found in the Postfix configuration
```

How can i resolve this Postfix Problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution [here](http://www.virtualmin.com/node/4735). The DNS on the machine should be enabled for it to work